# meteor up listen tcp 0.0.0.0:80: bind: address already in use

Tags: meteor, docker, web-deployment, meteor-up

I am using meteor up to deploy to a vps. I get the error in the title during the "Start Meteor" stage of `mup deploy`, along with a long list of

```
 Error response from daemon: endpoint (appname) not found
 Error response from daemon: No such container: (appname)-frontend
```

etc.

I have tried changing the `imagePort` value for docker in mup.js but I still get the same error, still for 0.0.0.0:80

Comment: "Address already in use" means that there already is a program bound to the address you try to use. Do you have a web-server or other program running that listens on that address? Perhaps you should use another port number for your application?

Comment: sometimes some programs keep this port open *cough* skype *cough* - use a connection viewer to track them. what OS do you use?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I tried to change the port but still got the error saying port 80 was in use. Presumably I didn't change the port in the correct way/ place

Comment: @OvidiuDolha macOS Sierra

Comment: Does the address already in use refer to the address being in use on my machine or the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case there is already an application that uses port 80. You can either remove that app and go ahead and redeploy, or you can change the port that your meteor application is going to be using, like so:

```
module.exports = {
  servers: { ... },
  meteor: {
    name: ...,
    path: ...
    buildOptions: ...
    env: {
      PORT: 3000,
      ROOT_URL: 'http://<your server ip>:3000',
      MONGO_URL: ...
    },

    deployCheckWaitTime: 120,
    enableUploadProgressBar: true,
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have run into a problem immediately afterwards at the verifying deployment stage but it seems completely unrelated. I'll mark your answer as correct when I can verify it is a separate issue

Comment: The verifying stage is nothing else that just meteor-up trying to curl the ROOT_URL address. If it doesn't receive any reply within the deployCheckWaitTime duration, it will say it failed. For my application, I set a delay of 120 seconds, which is usually enough for the meteor app to go online. So there are two things to try: 
1. Check if your app is up after 5 minutes
2. Check if the application port or outgoing traffic isn't firewalled

Comment: it still says in the logs `=> Starting meteor app on port:80` but im not getting the error